# removing python2 Mac as it is asking to upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, macos-catalina, u8darts

I tried  to install new packages such `dtale`, `u8darts`, but also upgrade old ones such `statsmodels` and many others but with not success and I have the following message:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python 
as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. 
More 
details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove 
support for this functionality.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement u8darts (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for u8darts
```

I have also tried to install the same packages using `pip3` as and I have python3 and that works. The only problem is, I am not able to import them although I am only using python3 on my IDEs (`Jupyter Notebook`and `VScode`). I am now trying to remove python2 from my systems and I am trying hard.

Comment: "I am now trying to remove python2 from my systems and I am trying hard" - you probably shouldn't remove Python 2 because a lot of system services may depend on it. If you manage to remove Python 2, the system may become unstable

Comment: @ForceBru what can I do? How can do it ?

Comment: You should check whether `pip3` installs the packages for the same version of Python 3 that you're importing them from

Comment: @ForceBru  It does install them but I am unable to import them. How can I check that , please?

Comment: Don't remove Python 2.  When pipping, make sure you `/path/to/python3 -m pip install whatever` with the python3 you intend to install into/import from. Specify python3 in your `PYTHON` variable.

Comment: @RichardBarber Sorry for being so daft. I am still with the same issue. The system itself tells me to upgrade within the following folder: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/` . the problem is , the /Contents/MacOS does not  exist. I can get to the `Python.app` the rest is unknown from my system. The same is happening when i go to python3.6 folder . the rest of the path is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had merged the Anconda, all I needed to do was to revert to bash using the command below:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

then reinstall Anaconda and choose home installation  (insuring that your `opt` folder does not contain any anaconda folder, you access by typing `space bar`and `/opt`on )

Now I am able to install all the packages I wanted to. No problem.